# Is there a database tool which shows a list of sql commands I have permission for?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-security, database

I talked to the developer of HeidiSQL about it and he told me I can query it by "show grants" command of sql, but i don't understand the result set coming from it.

> show grants // I execute query here
>
> GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'fsdb1user1'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD
>   'something'
>
> GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP,
>   REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, LOCK TABLES ON
>   `fsdb1`.* TO 'fsdb1user1'@'%'

mysql documentation says

> SHOW GRANTS displays only the privileges granted explicitly to the
>   named account. Other privileges might be available to the account, but
>   they are not displayed. For example, if an anonymous account exists,
>   the named account might be able to use its privileges, but SHOW GRANTS
>   will not display them.

I think there might be some software somewhere trying some queries and checks grants that way.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this user is allowed to do a lot.  Here is actually a good reference on all of these http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html#grant-privileges.

The user in question can run SELECT, UPDATE, and DELETE queries. They can CREATE tables and databases.  They can DROP tables, databases, and views. They can create and alter INDEXes.  They can ALTER table structures. They can use CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE. And finally, they can LOCK TABLES that they have SELECT privileges on.  In this case, the user can do this on any table in this database (`fsdb1`) and from any host.